# Rails - Render/add a sent SSE to a html element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

I'm trying to figure out how to render data that the server sends in an event. Let's say I write `sse.write "test"` or `sse.write {name: "test"}` to the browser. How would I be able to capture that into an element on the page? I know it can be viewed in curl... Could I implement that? I'm very new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use JavaScript for this.

```
// app.js file loaded in the page
sse = new EventSource('localhost:3000/sse');

sse.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  text = document.createTextNode(e.data);
  el.createElement('p').appendChild(text);
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}, false);
```